# How i send a object from Java like a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, java, android, laravel, retrofit2

I have an application Angular 7 frontend, Android mobile and a Laravel backend. I send an object in Angular 7 that is working fine on Laravel this is the object

```
{
  "mov_entry_id": 72507,
  "limitHour": "02/07/2019 13:40:27",
  "plate": null,
  "mov_vehicle_id": 1,
  "mov_vehicle_name": "Carro",
  "value": "8.00",
  "mov_area_id": 7,
  "mov_area_name": "AB",
  "mov_user_id": 1,
  "validated": "N",
  "updated_at": "02/07/2019 13:20:27",
  "mov_entry_ean13": "7800000725070",
  "created_at": "02/07/2019 13:20:27"
}
```

I'm sending a post method from angular to laravel this is the backend part that receive this object

```
           $entryObj = $request->input('entry');
           $userid = $request->input('userid');
           $hourValue = 0;
           $validatedDate;

           $response["success"] = 1;
           $response["message"] = "Entrada validada com blabla";
           $response['entryObj'] = $entryObj;
           $response['mov_entry_ean13'] = $entryObj["mov_entry_ean13"];
           return $response;
```

I get the object in **"$request->input('entry');"** in this part and I want to access the object like this **$entryObj["mov_entry_ean13"];**, when I send in Angular 7 with the Json as I show to you guys, my Laravel application access this is object fine, but my problem is on Android.

When I use Java in Android, I tried to make the object looks like the javascript way but with no success, I try JsonObject, JsonElement, and Map, this is my Retrofit API:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/validateentrymobi")
    public Call<JsonObject> validateTicket(
            @Field("entry")  JsonObject entry,
            @Field("userid") String user_id
    );
```

When I use I'm getting this error **"Illegal string offset "mov_entry_ean13""**, like is something wrong with my object that I'm sending, this is the object from java

```
{"mov_entry_id":72507,"plate":null,"mov_vehicle_id":1,"mov_vehicle_name":"Carro","value":"8.00","mov_area_id":7,"mov_area_name":"AB","mov_user_id":1,"validated":"N","mov_entry_ean13":"7800000725070","created_at":"02/07/2019 13:20:27","updated_at":"02/07/2019 13:20:27","validated_date":"2019-07-02 13:40:27"}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `@Body YourObject object` and Retrofit itself converts your object to json. Only thing you should care is creating proper pojo object in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a POJO and set up a json converter for Retrofit to use.

Setup Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // this requires implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
        .build()
```

Create a POJO class annotated with Gson

```
// this will act as the top level json object {}
class MyBody {
    @SerializedName("mov_entry_id")
    int movEntryId;

    // write your fields here
}
```

Use the POJO as the body for Retrofit request

```
// you don't need the form unless your backend requires it
    @POST("/api/validateentrymobi")
    public Call<ResponseBody> validateTicket( // @NOTE the return type, you can create a POJO class similar to how I created MyBody and replace ResponseBody with it. But ResponseBody should work.
        @Body MyBody myBody
    );
```